# SVD for String values

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, svd, dimensionality-reduction

I want to perform singular value decomposition on a large event data. Lets say I have 300+ attributes. And atlas 50% of them are string values. Like a city name and other possible string values.

SVD, as far as I know does dimensional reduction by computing distances between numeric values. How to achieve if there are so many string values?

EDIT:
re-phrase because of the comment and my misunderstanding. I want to know how dimensional reduction can be done for text values.

Comment: wikipedia says: `In linear algebra, the singular value decomposition (SVD) is a factorization of a real or complex matrix` - so no there are no distance calculations involved.

Comment: This isn't really about programming - seems much more appropriate for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)